# Problem with python superclass and subclasses

Tags: python, class, attributes, subclass

I am trying to build a storage system for a text-based game.
I wrote the following code to declare the needed classes:

```
class Item:
def __init__(self, name, count, health, damage):
    self.name = name
    self.count = count


class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, count, health, damage):
        super(Weapon, self).__init__(name, count, damage)
        self.damage = damage

class Food(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, count, health, damage):
        super(Food, self).__init__(name, count, damage, health)
```

To test if it was working, I added the following code to the bottom of the file:

```
Steak = Food("Steak", 4, 1.5, None)
print("You have {} {}s. Each of them gives you {} health points".format(Steak.count,Steak.name,Steak.health))
```

This results in an Attribute Error saying

```
AttributeError: 'Food' object has no attribute 'health'
```

What am I doing wrong? (I am kind of a beginner with classes)

Comment: Well, `Item.__init__` doesn't do anything with the `health` and `damage` parameters it receives. You didn't assign them to attributes: `self.health = health`

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks a lot, that fixed it! I wasn't aware enough while writing it...

Comment: Always use up all of the parameters in the `__init__` function. That's usually by assigning it as `self.something = something`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, count, health, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.count = count
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage


class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, count, health, damage):
        super(Weapon, self).__init__(name, count, health, damage)


class Food(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, count, health, damage):
        super(Food, self).__init__(name, count, damage, health)

Steak = Food("Steak", 4, 1.5, None)
print("You have {} {}s. Each of them gives you {} health points".format(Steak.count,Steak.name,Steak.health))
```

This gives you the output:

```
You have 4 Steaks. Each of them gives you None health points
```

Changes done:

1. attributes health, damage added to Item superclass
2. weapon class was also missing health attribute while init